# How to get angular2 [innerHtml] to work

Tags: angular

I  don't know what am doing wrong as no errors are report.

I have a component class

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 testhtml = "<p>Hello world</p>";
    constructor(){}

 }

}
```

And in my template file, I do something like this:

```
<div class="blog-post">[innerHtml]="testhtml"</div>
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Is there something else I need to import?

I am using angular-cli "version": "1.0.0-beta.26",

Comment: `<div class="blog-post" [innerHtml]="testhtml"></div>` <= its an attribute not the element content.

Comment: this worked for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/43862386/1048800

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Angular uses `{{property}}` for interpolation of values. That is the way that you would display plain text in your `div`, like so

**Solution 1:**

```
<div class="blog-post">{{testhtml}}</div>
```

But that will write out text, not HTML.

For HTML, you will need to bind to the property

**Solution 2:**

```
<div class="blog-post" [innerHtml]="testhtml"></div>
```

Note I moved the `[innerHtml]` to inside the `div` tag.

Leaving out the square brackets would bind to the attribute, so you would need to interpolate again

**Solution 3:**

```
<div class="blog-post" innerHtml="{{testhtml}}"></div>
```

The property binding (**Solution 2**) is the preferred method.

Comment: Out of curiosity why is solution two (`innerHtml="{{testhtml}}"`) preferred?

Comment: @JamieStreet Interpolation (solution 3) is actually converted into property binding (solution 2) - see the bottom of this section: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation----
The Angular documentation encourages the property binding syntax, so that is going to be familiar to other developers you work with.

Comment: @JaimeStreet I think it's clumsily worded. `[innerHtml]="testHtml"` is the preferred solution.

Comment: It would help add clarity to you answer if you would add headers for "Solution 1:" ... "Solution 2:" ... etc. Thanks for the answer. I have added these edits.

Comment: Hi @Cobus Kruger , If I run this code it works fine , But when I use `<input type="text" style="width:200px" name="fname">` It's even not display in html

Comment: Hi @Sachin Shah, you need add pipe to fix this, look this anwer: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/41089093/7452985

Answer (score 8):

You have to add attributes inside the tag like this.

```
<div class="blog-post" [innerHtml]="testhtml"></div>
```