# How to dynamically create div with dynamic Id in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am trying to add div with id using typescript but it is not assigning it. I am only getting div

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="one" [innerHtml]="htmlToAdd">

</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import * as shape from 'd3-shape';
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
   ngOnInit() {

    this.addDiv()

  }

  addDiv(){
     this.htmlToAdd = '<div class="two" id="myId">my div</div>';
  }

}
```

Comment: You probably have to bypass angular's security mechanisms. [check this](https://angular.io/guide/security)

Comment: @ochs.tobi please remove your comment. That's error inducing and completely false.

Comment: Please refer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/41979685/7458082](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41979685/7458082)

Comment: you cannot add dynamic HTML via innerHTML in angular even with domsanitizer . it just renders the HTML as markup. You need something like dynamic component loading

Comment: something like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic-component

Comment: @Niladri yes you can, but that's not recommended. Instead of advising a library, you should start by looking at the **[renderer](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2)**, which can do that for you.

Comment: @trichetriche there is also `ngComponentOutlet` in angular 4

Answer (score 0):

To give this an awnser, even tho it might not be an optimal solution. [Here is a Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-adgx4z)

In your component

```
trustedHtml: SafeHtml;

constructor(public s: DomSanitizer) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.addDiv();
}

public addDiv() {
    this.trustedHtml = this.s.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("<div class='two' id='myId'>my div</div>")
}
```

and your Html

```
<div [innerHTML]="trustedHtml"></div>
```