# Angular 6 - router-outlet - Loading external HTML with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am trying to develop json based dynamic template using Angular 6.

There are some use cases where I would like to load external html (might be from DB as a text ) with css (as a separate file as a text from DB) and use this for the corresponding router-outlet html.

For ex, We need to have a home.html and home.ts file for the below routing. Instead of having the html code inside home.html, I thought of loading from DB as a text and show the same. Here, I would like to get the corresponding css code also from DB without hard-coding css code in html.

Also, I need the corresponding JavaScript functions (say for dynamic html, i may have a delete link or cancel link) in a separate file. It would be similar to typescript. Can I load typescript file also dynamically?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
]
```

I can go with the below approach.

[How do I load an HTML page in a <div> using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636528/how-do-i-load-an-html-page-in-a-div-using-javascript)

But, trying to understand if there is any better approach for Angular 6.

Answer (score 2):

As I think the approach in the link is a good way of doing it.
Also you can use angular `innerHtml` property also.

```
<div class="home" [innerHtml]="testhtml"></div>
```

Here `testhtml` is your html getting from db.
For more information take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979458/how-to-get-angular2-innerhtml-to-work).

Comment: How can I have the CSS code required for this html separately? Meaning css code also from db.