# Angular innerHTML doesn´t recognise HTML tags

Tags: angular, innerhtml

I am learning Angular. On my first app, I installed [this text editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/froala-editor) to give users more power to format their texts than with a simple textarea.

It woriks fine. If for example I write

> I am Luis?
>
> I am 37 yrs old.
>
> This is  [the link](http://google.com) you gave me

I obtain this code, which will be inserted on the database and later show on the view when neccesary:

```
<p>How are you?<br><br>&nbsp;I am fine, thanks.    <br><br>&gt; This is &nbsp;<a href="https://github.com/froala/angular-froala-wysiwyg">the link</a> you gave me</p>
```

But when I try to show it on the view, I can´t manage the tags to be read as tags, and then, format my text.

I tried this:

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979458/how-to-get-angular2-innerhtml-to-work)

But it doesn´t work, I obtain the same string, including the HTML tags, but no formatting.

Must say, user.description is the property where that text is stored.

I read something about unsafe HTML, so following another suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding/41089093#41089093) , I also tried to add a pipe.

```
@Pipe({name: 'safeHtml'})
export class Safe {
  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}

  transform(style) {
    return    this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(style);
//return   this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
// return  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustXxx(style); - see docs
  }
}
```

And then:

```
 <div [innerHtml]="product.descripcion | safeHtml"></div>
```

But still doesn´t work. HTML tags are interpreted as normal text, so I can´t show them as I want.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems to work when I try it in StackBlitz? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-olno6h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Are you sure that the HTML code that you get is not encoded? When you say "I obtain this code" (e.g. `<p>How are you?<br>`), where do you see that code?

Answer (score 1):

OK, it seems it was only a matter of forgetfulness and a lack of good sleep.

I was simply inserting the div on a section which don´t exist on my view any more. I did on the correct place now and it works like a charm. Shame on me and thanks for your help to you all.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
<div [innerHtml]="product.descripcion | safeHtml"></div>
```

by:

```
 <div [innerHTML]="product.descripcion | safeHtml"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, innerHTML was actually the first way to do it but it didn´t worked either. innerHtml is how I saw in another web so I changed it to test