# Pull HTML code of sharepoint pages using REST API and display in angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, sharepoint

I am trying to sharepoint content like posts or sitepages in my angular application. Basically i am trying to find a way to pull the HTML equivalent code of sharepoint pages using REST API and display it, as it looked in sharepoint, in my web application. My application uses angular.

Please let me know if it is feasible, what are the available options.

Thanks in advance.

I googled a lot trying to figure out this before posting a open question here. But did not find much success. I could find API which pulls list details and data inside lists. But i am not sure sure if a list can contain a page and HTML code of page can be pulled.

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979458/how-to-get-angular2-innerhtml-to-work

Comment: This post does not serve my purpose. I am more like looking at sharepoint API which can share HTML code of sharepoint info